# Rendering JSON from Rails controller changes order of hash keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a hash in a Rails controller that looks like this:

```
{
  "-35": 10,
  "-16": 97,
  "-4": 205,
  "0": 825,
  "12": 116,
  "13": 93,
  "19": 112,
  "30": 77
}
```

Its keys are ordered from the lowest to the highest as number. When I call a route that yields this as JSON, I get the following output:

```
{
  "0": 825,
  "12": 116,
  "13": 93,
  "19": 112,
  "30": 77,
  "-35": 10,
  "-16": 97,
  "-4": 205
}
```

Rails changes the order during the rendering process.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: How is the generating of the hash done? Can you add the code?

Comment: @severin are you using ActiveModel::Serializers ?

Comment: If giving root name and format to `.to_json`, its not sorting. Nor u can send it as string `to_s` also not sorts without root name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, It's not sorting by default. If using json formatter, it does for you by default.

I have tested on httpie, curl and browser.
`render json: obj, status: :ok`

**Httpie**

```
#Input => Output
#Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

http URL => {
    "-16": 97,
    "-35": 10,
    "-4": 205,
    "0": 825,
    "12": 116,
    "13": 93,
    "19": 112,
    "30": 77
}

http --pretty=none URL =>
  {"-35":10,"-16":97,"-4":205,"0":825,"12":116,"13":93,"19":112,"30":77}
```

**Curl**

```
#Input => Output
#Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
curl http://lvh.me:3000/test =>
  {"-35":10,"-16":97,"-4":205,"0":825,"12":116,"13":93,"19":112,"30":77}
```

**RestClient Gem**

```
RestClient.get(URL).body =>
   "{\"-35\":10,\"-16\":97,\"-4\":205,\"0\":825,\"12\":116,\"13\":93,\"19\":112,\"30\":77}"

#no matter what returns as a string
```

But if to change plain: `render :plain => obj.to_json, status: :ok`

RestClient,Curl and HTTPie returns the same values, except Browsers :)

Just content-type is different `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

**Conclusion:**

As i understand, rails by default not sorts...

[Github about HTTP sort](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues/427)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly I should fix this on the receiving and not the sending end, right?

Comment: @Severin, Yes, if its Javascript front-end definitely do there.